# How to update CloudFront events to trigger lambda using boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudfront

Our goal is to allow switching between maintenance mode or main website that hosted in s3 and served through CloudFront.

We have tried using lambda@edge to return html and trigger it via CloudFront events `viewer request`

It's works fine, but now instead of updating CloudFront distribution via console, ***we want to update it using CLI (boto3)***. I have read boto3 documentation and can't find how to implement it. Is it possible to update CloudFront events via boto3, or is there another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you use [update_distribution](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudfront.html#CloudFront.Client.update_distribution) which allows you to specify `LambdaFunctionAssociations`.